# Wifi gone after installing backport of ath10k

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, backport

......Hello

I got a situation when I tried to install the ath10k driver for a 802.11ac supported wireless card by installing the backport releases.

My system is ubuntu 14.04, and my current kernel version is 3.13, the 11ac wireless card is an external chipsets connecting to my laptop with a serial port/USB adapter.

When I installed the backport, and rebooted, the system didn't load the driver of my original built-in wifi card. I ran ifconfig and iwconfig, the original wlan0 disappeared.

Questions:

1. What exactly did backport do? Did that just update my kernel version? There was a new wireless driver of a external chipsets in that backport. Did that mean,when I installed that,it just cover and disable the original wifi functions?
2. Now I can only reach the internet by Lan cable? How could I bring back the driver of the original wifi function? Does that influence the ath10k driver what I need to deal with? Can the two drivers,two functions just coexist?

thanks in advance!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Backports installs the networking drivers from a newer kernel, 3.16, for example, into an earlier kernel, in your case 3.13. Since you can select which drivers to install and not install all the wireless drivers that you don't need, 'defconfig ath10k', if you have two devices, you run the risk of installing conflicting cfg80211 and mac80211 pieces, as you have found!

You might try also installing the driver for your existing device from the same backports package and see if it helps.

Also, Network Manager will generally allow one connection or the other, not both.